# Json data conversion

Tags: json

My requirement a little odd so apologize in advance.
I have a sample json file like below -

```
{"value":"test","value1":"test1","value2":"test2","value3":"test3"}
```

So I have 4 columns in Json , how do I merge the 3rd and 4th column into a single string column and end up with 3 Json columns

I can convert like below

```
{
    "value": "test",
    "value1": "test1",
    "test": {
        "value2": "test2",
        "value3": "test3"
    }
}
```

But I want to store the entire value of test as String not another Json type
 I want to store the value " {"value2":"test2","value3":"test3"} " as String

Comment: something like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ?? also you can't display what you want since the oneliner json is not representing your output properly

Comment: you need to add inner jsonobject

Comment: you need: ```{"value":"test","value1":"test1","test":{"value2":"test2","value3":"test3"}}```

Comment: What is your exact desired output and what scripting language are you using?

Comment: U need this type of json?     {
      "test": {
        "value2": "test2",
        "value": "test",
        "value1": "test1",
        "value3": "test3"
      }
    }

Comment: @mickmackusa - I can use python/unix

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - Thats exactly what I created but if you create a schema you will see that value of test is another nested Json , I want to store the value " {"value2":"test2","value3":"test3"} " as String

Comment: That information needs to go into the tags of your question.  Please edit to clarify your question requirements.